# Summarize Excel cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Can someone please advise how to proceed?

I have a data base including 3 columns and 22000 rows. In the first column, I manually add value=1 for which cells in the second column that is critical and leave the rest of the cells empty.

In another sheet, I need to summarize this data base for another purpose. So only the cells(in the second column) with value 1 in the first column are important for me.

If I use "If" formula combined with VLOOKUP, something like `+IF(MATRIX!A:A=1,VLOOKUP(MATRIX!B:B, MATRIX!B:E,1,0),)` it will still give me the empty cells as well, and I will have another file with 22000 rows while I only need the critical ones.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Auto Filters** under the **Data** Menu.

Select the column headers, and do "Auto Filter"
A drop down will appear at the top each column.
Hit the drop down, and uncheck all values, but **1**.
Hit Ok or Apply, and it should be done.